# Java EE - No sirve el c:foreach en JSP

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee, servlets

Perdonen la molestia e ignorancia, tengo un archivo *JSP* y una clase *Servlet*, no sé por qué el `<c:foreach>` no funciona en mi *JSP*.

Tengo un *servlet* con unas pocas líneas de código en el método `doPost()`. Lo que hace es enviar un arreglo de productos a un JSP llamado `index.jsp` por medio de *RequestDispatcher* para comunicar los dos archivos. El problema es cuando este array de objetos viaja al `index.jsp` y ejecuto este jsp, no se muestra el arreglo de objetos en pantalla. Lo mismo me pasa en *Netbeans* y en *Eclipse*, y eso que están las JSTL librerías.

Por favor, ayúdenme con esta parte, voy un mes y no puedo avanzar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. La pregunta está bien planteada (+1 por usar un ejemplo básico) pero el código debería ir como texto; las imágenes pueden ser difíciles de ver para según que personas. Puedes modificar la pregunta haciendo click en "Editar".

Comment: El código parece correcto, pero ¿cómo estás invocando al servlet? ¿haces un POST o un GET?

Comment: Solamente creé un servlet, y escribí directo en el método doPost y nada mas

Comment: Pero ¿cómo llamas al servlet desde el navegador? ¿Un form? ¿Le metes la URL "a mano"?

Comment: No deberías usar <c:out/> para mostrar los elementos?